# Nginx redirect within the same server

Tags: nginx, redirect

If I have a server `foo.com` which has a root directory `~/public_html/foo`. For some reasons I want to use the same server config but point the request from `foo.com/test/` to `~/public_html/test`. Any hints on how can I do that? `rewrite`? `location`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`alias`](http://nginx.org/r/alias). That should be about all the hint you asked for.